# How do you save each element of a list in a .txt file, one per line?

Tags: python, list, text, io

I have a list, `pList`. I want to save it to a text (`.txt`) file, so that each element of the list is saved on a new line in the file. How can I do this?

This is what I have:

```
def save():
    import pickle
    pList = pickle.load(open('primes.pkl', 'rb'))
    with open('primes.txt', 'wt') as output:
      output.write(str(pList))
    print "File saved."
```

However, the list is saved in just one line on the file.
I want it so every number (it solely contains integers) is saved on a new line.

Example:

```
pList=[5, 9, 2, -1, 0]
#Code to save it to file, each object on a new line
```

Desired Output:

```
5
9
2
-1
0
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply open your file, join your list with the desired delimiter, and print it out.

```
outfile = open("file_path", "w")
print >> outfile, "\n".join(str(i) for i in your_list)
outfile.close()
```

Since the list contains integers, it's needed the conversion. (Thanks for the notification,  Ashwini Chaudhary).

No need to create a temporary list, since the generator is iterated by the join method (Thanks, again, Ashwini Chaudhary).

Comment: The list contains integers, so the `join()` call will raise `TypeError` here. `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`

Comment: No need of those `[]` inside `join()`, use `"\n".join(str(i) for i in your_list)`

Comment: Why `print >>` when `outfile.write` will work on both py2k and py3k?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `map` with `str` here:

```
pList = [5, 9, 2, -1, 0]
with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(map(str, pList)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer to get a function that adds an item to a new line for the given file

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203890/325499

```
def addToFile(file, what):
    f = open(file, 'a').write(what+"\n")
```

So for your question, instead of just passing the list to the file, you will need to iterate through the list.

```
for item in pList:
    addToFile(item)
```

Comment: I don't think there's a need of defining such extra function, and opening and closing a file for every item of the list will cost too many I/O operations.